# Popover dentro de uma tabela não funciona

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-3, popover

Estou tentando colocar um popover dentro de uma linha de uma tabela que é montada dinamicamente de acordo com os dados vindo da base de dados. Testei fora da tabela e funcionou, mas dentro da linha da tabela não.

meu Js está assim

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
        });
```

meu html está assim

```
<tbody ng-repeat="dis in distritos ">
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{dis.idDistrito}}</td>
                      <td>{{dis.nome}}</td>
                      <td>{{dis.codigoDne}}</td>    
                     <td><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>

                    </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Veja no console se está retornando erro, mais creio que seja a falta do `jQuery` ... `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: eu testei fora do `<td>` e funcionou

Comment: Pode ser possível que esteja acontecendo algum conflito, algo do tipo, veja no console, porque eu testei aqui e funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está apenas no apontamento, seu jQuery não está disparando o popover.

Adicione um atributo `trigger` ao `<a>` dentro de `<td>`:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="teste" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
```

E faça uma leve alterada no evento, idicando pra ele adicionar o popover no momento do hover:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"').on('mouseover',function(){
        $(this).popover();   
    })
});
```

Exemplo funcional no fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AnthraxisBR/nerpsqt7/2/

OBS: inclua o jQuery sempre antes do arquivo js do bootstrap.

Comment: Creio que não seja isso, pois ele disse que colocou fora do `td` e funcionou

Comment: É isso mesmo, ele não tem trigger, por mais que instancie a popover, não vai disparar.

Comment: Veja aqui que eu testei no [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gecorub/edit?html,output) no caso aqui, que esta igual ao dele tem que clicar pra aparecer. Então a pergunta não está clara.